# Twitter Bootstrap 3 Modal and jQuery Selectors

Tags: ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the jquery datepicker plugin bound to any elements with class="datepicker".

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

I am loading a form with:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##modal" href="profile/eventnew"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
```

In the form that is loading I have a field with `class='datepicker'`, however it is not getting picked up by the datepicker plugin as the element was not there when `$(".datepicker").datepicker();` was executed.

I know that with events, I can use the jquery `.on()` method to bind to ajax loaded elements, but there is no event here.

How do I bind something such as `$(".datepicker").datepicker();` to Ajax loaded elements?

Many Thanks

Comment: Since you are initiating a plugin it has to be done after the target elements are loaded in the dom... there is no delegated initialization of plugins!!!

I think you can have a look at the shown event from bootstrap model

Comment: Where does `datepicker` come from? It may have a delegation option. Also `data-target='##modal'`? Two hashes / pound signs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
})
```